# Cannot Decode NFC Message

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, encoding, nfc

I am developing a Xamarin Forms app which opens up a view with the view model being determined by data transferred via an NFC tag using the Plugins.NFC package. I have functionality to encode an ID to the tag as well as read the tag. My problem is, it seems that when the NFC tag is read, I cannot do anything with the resulting string as it throws an error due to what I believe is it not being decoded correctly.

I have tried two different methods of structuring the data on the NFC chip such as a JSON object as well as just an ID of the object. What's weird is when I set a breakpoint after reading the tag, the string appears to look fine and show up, and JsonLint even responded with the JSON being valid when I attempted to use JSON in the tag. The error is thrown once I begin to use the string of the tag content in any way. 
When I was trying to use JSON in the tag, and I would go to deserialize it, I would get an error saying that there was a parsing error at line 0 position 0.

When I am trying to use an ID (int) in the tag, when I try to parse it I get the error "Input string was not in the correct format"
Now I've determined that it's got to be something with encoding / decoding the NFC tag because if I use an app to write something to the tag, it works flawlessly, but when I write to the tag in my app, that's when the issue arises.

This is the function to read the tag. Notice the commented code as previous attempts to decode.

```
async void Current_OnMessageReceived(ITagInfo tagInfo)
    {
        if (tagInfo == null)
        {
            await ShowAlert("No tag found");
            return;
        }

        // Customized serial number
        var identifier = tagInfo.Identifier;
        var serialNumber = NFCUtils.ByteArrayToHexString(identifier, ":");
        var title = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serialNumber) ? $"Tag [{serialNumber}]" : "Tag Info";

        if (!tagInfo.IsSupported)
        {
            await ShowAlert("Unsupported tag (app)", title);
        }
        else if (tagInfo.IsEmpty)
        {
            await ShowAlert("Empty tag", title);
        }
        else
        {
            IDatabaseManager db = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<IDatabaseManager>() as IDatabaseManager;
            //var first = tagInfo.Records[0];
            //string msg = first.Message;
            //string msgHex = NFCUtils.ByteArrayToHexString(tagInfo.Records[0].Payload);
            //string msg = Convert.ToString(msgHex);
            //string msg = NFCUtils.GetMessage(tagInfo.Records[0]);
            string msg = NFCUtils.GetMessage(tagInfo.Records[0]);
            try
            { 
                //tring messageEncoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tagInfo.Records[0].Payload);
                int cardId = int.Parse(msg);
                var card = await db.GetCard(cardId);
                //Entities.Card card = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entities.Card>(msg);
                var model = await CardModel.FromCard(card);
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ViewCardPage(model));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

And Here is the function that writes to the tag

```
void Current_OnTagDiscovered(ITagInfo tagInfo, bool format)
    {
        if (!CrossNFC.Current.IsWritingTagSupported)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var record = new NFCNdefRecord
            {
                TypeFormat = NFCNdefTypeFormat.WellKnown,
                MimeType = "text/plain",
                Payload = NFCUtils.EncodeToByteArray(selectedCard.Card.Id.ToString())
                //Payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedCard.Card);)
            };

            if (!format && record == null)
                throw new Exception("Record can't be null.");

            tagInfo.Records = new[] { record };

            //if (format)
            //{ 
            //  CrossNFC.Current.ClearMessage(tagInfo);
            //}

            CrossNFC.Current.PublishMessage(tagInfo, false);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            //await ShowAlert(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

[image: Reading tag breakpoint hit]

Comment: is it `int.Parse()` that throws the exception?  What is the value of `msg`?

Comment: @Jason int.Parse() as well as when I tried to use JSON and deserialize it both throw the error. The value of msg in the above example can be seen in the screenshot as "17"

Comment: if Int.Parse() is failing than it can't be "17" - I would look at it with the hex viewer to verify that there aren't any invisible characters that are causing the parse to fail.

Comment: in the screenshot you are parsing `msg.Normalize()`, are you sure that returns the same string?

Comment: @Jason I have tried with and without normalizing, I believe the issue could be within the hex value as you recommended, let me check that out.

Comment: @Jason https://imgur.com/rzSwYam here's a screenshot of the hex values of the "17" text

Comment: Well obviously that’s the problem.  I don’t anything about NFC but there must be some encoding happening

Comment: I appreciate the help with narrowing down the issue I will try to encode it differently and get back to you!

Comment: It looks like that it's coming through in the value of a hex base 16 but I can't seem to convert the value back to a string or int

Comment: I don't think that's it.  It shows 6 bytes in hex, not two.  There is some filler.  When you write the message, you use `Payload = NFCUtils.EncodeToByteArray`, but when you read it, you use `string msg = NFCUtils.GetMessage(tagInfo.Records[0]);`.  Are you sure those two methods are complementary?  Where does NFCUtils come from?

Comment: NFCUtils is a class from the Plugins.NFC package so I assumed they would work together plus the sample code uses them. Here's the class https://github.com/franckbour/Plugin.NFC/blob/master/src/Plugin.NFC/Shared/NFCUtils.shared.cs

Comment: it looks like that should work.  If you look at the entire tagInfo object in the debugger, how is the data encoded before you call GetMessage?  You might also file an issue on GitHub and see what the author has to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that this could be an issue with the Plugin.NFC package. The workaround I've found was that if I use a URI rather than text, it was encoded correctly.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer , which will help more people :)